# How can I search data from a json response and show in List View

Tags: android, json, api, response, affiliate

**My API Link is here**

[Hotel Search API](http://engine.hotellook.com/api/v2/search/start.json?iata=HKT&checkIn=2017-05-14&checkOut=2017-05-18&adultsCount=2&customerIP=192.168.10.33&childrenCount=1&lang=en&currency=USD&timeout=20&waitForResult=1&marker=58532&signature=d9ce80c03cc293e1dfaa42e2c9fe8907)

[Response in JSON Editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5M1OK.png)

please suggest me what I have to do.

I actually want to store this json response and and show some data from that
 response to user that user search.

Let say user search avari Hotel so I have to show just data of avai hotel to

user from that response.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You should search before asking.

Comment: I think sir you have not read my Question.

Comment: I am asking that how can I store that response for future use for user. I don't want to show whole data in list view just show user searched data from that response that I have already fetch.

Comment: You can store the fetched data into a database or SharedPreferences

Comment: sir pleas take a look on this API.
http://engine.hotellook.com/api/v2/search/start.json?iata=HKT&checkIn=2017-05-14&checkOut=2017-05-18&adultsCount=2&customerIP=192.168.10.33&childrenCount=1&lang=en&currency=USD&timeout=20&waitForResult=1&marker=58532&signature=d9ce80c03cc293e1dfaa42e2c9fe8907

canI store this whole data in sqlite DB?

Comment: This is the exact thing you want http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27941986/how-to-cache-parsed-json-for-offline-usage

Comment: Still this question is duplicate

Comment: Thank you so much It's help full